# Different results with different link functions

Tags: r, regression, mathematical-statistics, generalized-linear-model, link-function

I have used the R package `eventglm` to construct pseudo observations, and want to estimate the relative risk and the risk difference for exposure with age adjustment.

First, I use the identity link function, and calculate the risk difference and the risk in each group. This gives me 3 values, let’s say

Risk group 1: 0.24
Risk group 2: 0.42
Risk difference: -0.18

If I calculate the relative risk based on the estimates above, I get 0.57.

However When I use the log link function and get a relative risk of: O.77, which is clearly different from 0.57

It might be obvious, but can anyone explain to me why I see this difference?

If I don’t adjust for age, the two estimation methods give exactly the same result.

Comment: Can you give some more details? The family function used? Show us some of the code

Comment: If you change the model, you will naturally get different results. Surely that can't be surprising. The only context where changing the link won't changed the fitted values or likelihood ratio tests is when you are fitting a oneway layout of distinct groups, e.g., if the model formula is a single factor.